# My laravel project found http 500 error in live server and i got error_log like this

Tags: laravel, deployment, cpanel

my laravel project work well in localhost but while i uoload to the webserver i found http 500 error
and error_log file is look like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFwZv.png)

Comment: run **composer install**

Comment: copy your all local files to your cpnel directory

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your classmap is incorrect. It typically happens when you run `composer install` in a folder and then rename it or one of its parents.

Run `composer install` from the root of your project.

Comment: can i remove this?

Comment: It also seems like he's using a CPanel, so I don't know if he has access to the console for that. Another thing you could do is to upload your vendor directory along with your project folder.

Comment: @DhanPulami remove what?